# Is possible to share a xib between a UITableViewCell and a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I am looking to factorize some code and xib for a view design shared between a UITableViewCell and UICollectionViewCell. Is it possible share the same xib between a UITableViewCell and UICollectionViewCell? or Is it possible to share the same xib for a subview?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this by just using a UIView super view. Then each of those cells would just need to load the shared view into the cells.  I think you may lose the ability for auto layout to work with UIAutomaticDimension for autosizing cells.